# Auto adjust dependent state and vice versa when changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, redux

So I am using Airbnb's [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) library for a calendar:

### Component

```
export const Calendar = ({setDates, startDate, endDate, setFocused, focusedInput}) => {
return (
    <div className="input-group">
        <div className="input-group_addon">
            <i className="icon-date-inactive" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <DateRangePicker
            startDate={startDate}
            endDate={endDate}
            focusedInput={focusedInput}
            displayFormat="ddd, D MMM"
            onDatesChange={setDates}
            onFocusChange={setFocused}
        />
    </div>
    )
}
```

### Container

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        startDate: state.model.model.calendar.startDate,
        endDate: state.model.model.calendar.endDate,
        focusedInput: state.model.model.calendar.focusedInput
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setDates: (dates) => {
            dispatch(marketplaceSetDates(dates.startDate, dates.endDate));
        },
        setFocused: (focusedInput) => {
            dispatch(marketplaceSetFocused(focusedInput));
        }
    }
}

export const CalendarContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calendar);
```

### Actions

```
export function marketplaceSetDates(startDate, endDate) {
    return {
        type: 'MARKETPLACE_MODEL_DATES_CHANGE',
        dates: {
            start: startDate,
            end: endDate
        }
    }
}

export function marketplaceSetFocused(focusedInput) {
    return {
        type: 'MARKETPLACE_MODEL_FOCUS_CHANGE',
        focusedInput: focusedInput
    }
}
```

### Reducer

```
let initialState = {
    model: {
        calendar: {
            startDate: moment().add(1, 'day'),
            endDate: moment().add(4, 'day'),
            focusedInput: null
        }
    },
}

export const modelReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let newState = {};
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'MARKETPLACE_MODEL_FOCUS_CHANGE':
            newState = Object.assign({}, state);
            newState.model.calendar.focusedInput = action.focusedInput;
            return newState;

        case 'MARKETPLACE_MODEL_DATES_CHANGE':
            newState = Object.assign({}, state);

            newState.model.calendar.startDate = (action.dates.start === null) ?
            state.model.calendar.startDate : action.dates.start;

            newState.model.calendar.endDate = (action.dates.end === null) ?
            state.model.calendar.startDate.add(4, 'day') : action.dates.end;

            return newState;
    }
    return state;
}
```

The one rule for our calendar is that, whenever the user select a new `startDate` or `endDate`, it must automatically adjust to be at least **3 days apart**.

For example as you could see, the initial state sets the dates to be tomorrow and 4 days from now.

- So it would be **Oct 19 -> Oct 22**.
- If I click for a new `startDate` on **Oct 24**, *(NOTE THAT IT IS NOT WITHIN THE RANGE OF THE PREVIOUS DAYS)*, thus the `endDate` must automatically adjust to **Oct 27**.
- Same goes when clicking on an `endDate` before the selected range, the `startDate` must automatically adjust accordingly, 3 days before the selected `endDate`.

But with my current code, when I click on the `startDate`, **both `startDate` and `endDate` is set to 3 days after**, which should only be `endDate`'s value.

I suspect the reason behind this is due to mutating the state in `redux` is asynchronous, thus the `state.model.calendar.startDate.add(4, 'day')` goes first before the `newState.model.calendar.startDate = ...`, am I correct in my assumption?

Otherwise, I would like help for a workaround.

Comment: In browser/node javascript sequential lines of code are always synchronous unless you have an async block (created via a function on a callback that does IO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:
Change the add days function to:
`state.model.calendar.startDate.clone().add(4, 'day')`

I believe the issue is with the momentjs add function.
From the docs:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

> #### Add
>
> ...
>   Mutates the original moment by adding time.

This means that when you do 
`state.model.calendar.startDate.add(4, 'day')` it actually changes the value of `state.model.calendar.startDate`.

So ideally, you should copy the moment and then change it using [clone()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/)

Comment: I see, no wonder. I thought it's due to asynchronicity. Many thanks!